# Which of the below sentences is correct to express "you might like X but I do not"?

Tags: expressions

I was trying to mock one of my friends saying "Unlike you, I do not have this trait" but then I thought, I should have said "Like you, I do not have this trait".  Till now, it seems to me that both are correct. The first one expresses that "you have this trait but I do not have" and the second one expresses "I do not have this trait like you have".

So am I correct in this interpretation? Or is there a better way to say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify by removing the negative.

> Like you, I have blue eyes.

means you have blue eyes and so do I.

> Unlike you I have blue eyes

means I have blue eyes and you do not.

So

> Unlike you I do not have this trait

means I do not have this trait, but you do.

> Like you I do not have this trait

means neither of us has it.